# MySQL order by not working with join

Tags: mysql, join

I am attempting to create a mysql query that ranks MMA fighters based on their score, and whether or not they are professional, and their weight class, together creating a fighters division. I have a table with all of the fighters that contains their weight, status (professional or amateur), and a bunch of other columns. I also have a table that contains scores that are calculated from all of their fights. The records need to be ordered by both division and score, but I can only get my query to order by the division:

```
INSERT INTO fa_rankings (fighter_id, rank, division)
SELECT 
    fa_scores.fighter_id,
    @r := CASE WHEN @div <> f_division THEN 1 ELSE @r+1 END as f_rank,
    @div := f_division
FROM
    (SELECT @div := NULL) d,
    (SELECT @r := 0) r,
    fa_scores
JOIN (SELECT fa_fighters.fighter_id,
        CONCAT(
            IF(status = 'professional', 'a', 'b'),
            CASE
                WHEN weight < 126 THEN 0
                WHEN weight BETWEEN 126 AND 135 THEN 1
                WHEN weight BETWEEN 136 AND 145 THEN 2
                WHEN weight BETWEEN 146 AND 155 THEN 3
                WHEN weight BETWEEN 156 AND 170 THEN 4
                WHEN weight BETWEEN 171 AND 185 THEN 5
                WHEN weight BETWEEN 186 AND 205 THEN 6
                WHEN weight BETWEEN 206 AND 265 THEN 7
                ELSE 8 END) as f_division
    FROM fa_fighters
    ORDER BY f_division ASC) as fighters using (fighter_id)
ORDER BY score DESC
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with where the last order by statement is, but I can't figure out where else to put it, because it doesn't work with in the joined query. Right now this query generates the following:

```
Rankings Table                   Compared with Scores
+------------+------+----------+ +-------+
| fighter_id | rank | division | | score |
+------------+------+----------+ +-------+
| 131        | 1    | a1       | | 0     |
| 23         | 2    | a1       | | 34    |
| 332        | 3    | a1       | | 4     |
| 1233       | 1    | a2       | | 0     |
| 643        | 2    | a2       | | 44    |
+------------+------+----------+ +-------+
```

EDIT: I had  previous query that did not use a join, but that only grouped by whether or not the fighter was professional, and that query did apply the rankings correctly, so I suspect it has something to with the join.

EDIT: Here is the output from my select

```
SELECT * ,
(SELECT CONCAT_WS(  ' ', f_name, l_name ) FROM fa_fighters WHERE fa_fighters.fighter_id = fa_rankings.fighter_id)
AS name,
(SELECT score FROM fa_scores WHERE fa_scores.fighter_id = fa_rankings.fighter_id) 
AS score
FROM  `fa_rankings` 
WHERE 1 
ORDER BY division, rank ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[image: select result]

EDIT: It is ordering the records by score, but at the wrong point; it is ordering them by score after it has determined the rank, so that the raw table is ordered by score, but the fighters do not have the correct rank associated with them. I need the query to order the records by score before it runs the rank counter and determines each fighters rank. This is a problem of when the ORDER BY is being appiled when the query is executed, I just don't know where to put it.

Comment: Remove Order by Divison from Inner query and put in outer query ..

Comment: I had it in the outer query but it didn't work, it was not ordering by division, EDIT, it would give all the fighters a ranking of 1 or 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that moving the "ORDER BY score DESC" into the joined subquery produced the correct result:

```
INSERT INTO fa_rankings (fighter_id, rank, division)
SELECT 
    fa_scores.fighter_id,
    @r := CASE WHEN @div <> f_division THEN 1 ELSE @r+1 END as f_rank,
    @div := f_division
FROM
    (SELECT @div := NULL) d,
    (SELECT @r := 0) r,
    fa_scores
JOIN (SELECT fa_fighters.fighter_id,
        CONCAT(
            IF(status = 'professional', 'a', 'b'),
            CASE
                WHEN weight < 126 THEN 0
                WHEN weight BETWEEN 126 AND 135 THEN '1'
                WHEN weight BETWEEN 136 AND 145 THEN '2'
                WHEN weight BETWEEN 146 AND 155 THEN '3'
                WHEN weight BETWEEN 156 AND 170 THEN '4'
                WHEN weight BETWEEN 171 AND 185 THEN '5'
                WHEN weight BETWEEN 186 AND 205 THEN '6'
                WHEN weight BETWEEN 206 AND 265 THEN '7'
                ELSE '8' END) as f_division
    FROM fa_fighters
    ORDER BY 
        f_division ASC,
        #the score column in the form of a subquery
        (select score from fa_scores where fa_scores.fighter_id = fa_fighters.fighter_id) DESC) 
    as fighters using (fighter_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your table TABLE have an index on division and that's why that the output looks like that.

If you don't specify an `order by` when you make a query, the table will not have any order AT ALL, even with an index you'll have some kind of order but it's not 100% accuracy in huge tables.

Resuming, In your query you have an INSERT with order and joins, but that doesn't mean when you make a `select.....` the output will be the same order as the input.  My advice is always specify `ORDER BY` and have a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY (at least one of them).

Comment: I should mention that the table at the bottom is what I got from a select query that orders by rank (and selects the score) after I ran this; some fighters with the highest score in their division are ranked 15 or 20, and some with 0 are ranked 1. Also there is no index on division or score

Comment: @GregRozmarynowycz Can you execute `show create table tablename` command and show it? and also copy and paste the query and the result directly

Comment: CREATE TABLE `fa_rankings` (
 `fighter_id` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
 `rank` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `division` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 KEY `fighter_id` (`fighter_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: @GregRozmarynowycz and where is the select that display that result witouh order?, what I'm getting is that if you make select * from fa_rankings the order will be like the one you put in your posts?